# Phonegap not showing accents spanish words

Tags: html, cordova, character-encoding

I've developed an app that consumes a web service from a server, the server gives it's response in JSON. Most of the news are on spanish so the have accents on their letters. They are coming on the JSON file as

```
&Aacute;
```

for example. But when the page loads it gives me this �

What can i do?

EDIT

Here's my header:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<title>PhoneGap</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="photoswipe.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile.structure-1.0.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-mobile-1.0-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="klass.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="code.photoswipe.jquery-3.0.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="service.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
</head>
```

Answer (score 4):

Did you set the encoding to utf-8 in your HTML page header like so

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: I just added and still doesn't works. I put my header in the edit.

Comment: Are you using a particular font ? What device/browser are you trying you app on ?

Comment: No, I'm not specifying any font, I'm using jQuery Mobile.

I'm testing it on Chrome and on my Motorola Droid running CM7

Comment: I guess you could try to go to spanish website with your mobile to see if accents are displaying. Then you'll know if it's coming from you app or your mobile..

Comment: I am using mysql, I generate a json in php, which contains html tags with texts containing accents: to encode accents I use `utf8_encode` and after I call `htmlspecialchars` to convert special html chars to entities. On the other side there is an html page that uses jquery to consume that php (which delivers this "poluted" json). The html page meta tag is utf-8 (it renders accents nice automatically!). To decode the html entities I use a js `function decodeEntities(s) {var x =document.createElement('textarea');x.innerHTML=s; return x.value;}`

Answer (score 2):

Web programming is a mess when we talk about accents.  I had the same problem this week, when trying to create a mobile app in **French** with jquery mobile and mySQL.  The DB (which is UTF-8) was full of accentuated words (é, à...) and needed to be displayed in the same way on interface, not the �.  The problem was also there when it was time to save to DB, standard way was sending weird caracters instead of standard accents.

I've tried the meta trick and a lot of others but finally I solved my problem this way:

Every time I need to display something, I use: **htmlentities**($something, **ENT_QUOTES**)

like:
`<input type="text" name="middle_name" value="<?php echo htmlentities($middle_name, ENT_QUOTES);?>">`

Every time I need to save something, I use: **utf8_decode**($something)

```
$allValues .= "'". utf8_decode($val) . "', ";
```

In regards to javascript functions like alert(), the way is to use octal represantation like :

```
$message = "Enregistrement ajout\\351" ;
...
<script language="JavaScript">
   alert(<?php echo $message ; ?>);
</script>
```

Go there to have octal numbers: http://www.pjb.com.au/comp/diacritics.html

This ways I was able to display and save all accentuated words.
Is it the right way to do, probably not, but there is not a lot of reference on the web on how to solve this problem for good.  Believe me I've spent a lot of time searching...

Have fun...

Comment: the crazy black magick we have to do because of legacy stuff (mess) :D